# Script to change the end of a url to reflect the current month Ex 04/01/2019

Tags: javascript, html

I'm working on a web application that will have a div that holds a view of a link. This link will change every month and I was wondering if there is a way to change the ending of the URL to reflect the first of the current month.

at the end of the URL you see `monthDate=04/01/2019` I would want this part of the URL to change on it own when its the next month. For example, even though today is 04/05/2019 all I need in the URL is to be pointing to the first day of the month `monthDate=04/01/2019`. If today was `05/20/2019` I would need the end of the URL to point to `monthDate=05/01/2019`

Here is the div I have.

```
<div>
<iframe frameborder="0" scrolling="yes" src="http://zumdb-prod.itg.ti.com/zum/AppServlet?action=aotoolFe&jspURL=clusterTools/toolsetFe.jsp&fegoaltype=RAW&eedbListName=ZUM_Wet_Met_Brooks_IOC_sorters&facility=DMOS5&monthDate=04/01/2019" style="width:100%; height:550px; -ms-zoom: .995; -webkit-transform: scale(.995); -webkit-transform-origin: 0 0; -o-transform: scale(0.995); -o-transform-origin: 0 0;"></iframe>
</div>
```

Update:

I used @danny_o comment and I now have this but only one of them gets populated correctly. Am I doing something wrong?

```
<div>
    <iframe id="myFrame1" frameborder="0" scrolling="yes" src="" style="width:100%; height:550px; -ms-zoom: .995; -webkit-transform: scale(.995); -webkit-transform-origin: 0 0; -o-transform: scale(0.995); -o-transform-origin: 0 0;"></iframe>
         </div>
<div>
    <iframe id="myFrame" frameborder="0" scrolling="yes" src="" style="width:100%; height:550px; -ms-zoom: .995; -webkit-transform: scale(.995); -webkit-transform-origin: 0 0; -o-transform: scale(0.995); -o-transform-origin: 0 0;"></iframe>
         </div>
```

In my script sections, I have

```
     <script>
        const getDate = () => {
            let newDate = new Date();
            let year = newDate.getFullYear();
            let month = newDate.getMonth() + 1;
            month = month < 10 ? '0' + month : month;
            return month + '/' + '01/' + year;
          }

          document.getElementById('myFrame1').src = 'http://zumdb-prod.itg.ti.com/zum/AppServlet?action=aotool&jspURL=clusterTools/toolset.jsp&fegoaltype=RAW&eedbListName=ZUM_Wet_Met_Brooks_IOC_sorters&facility=DMOS5&monthDate='.concat(getDate());
          document.getElementById('myFrame').src = 'http://zumdb-prod.itg.ti.com/zum/AppServlet?action=aotoolFe&jspURL=clusterTools/toolsetFe.jsp&fegoaltype=RAW&eedbListName=ZUM_Wet_Met_Brooks_IOC_sorters&facility=DMOS5&monthDate='.concat(getDate());

        </script>


The error I get is:

Uncaught SyntaxError: Identifier 'getDate' has already been declared
```

Comment: Having forward slashes in a URL will be problematic unless you have folders of that path.Beyond that, you've told us what you want, but what have you tried? We expect that you'll do your research and make an attempt before posting.

Comment: To get that date is easy `function getDate() { let d = new Date(); return new Date(d.getFullYear(), d.getMonth(), 1); }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const getDate = () => {
  let newDate = new Date();
  let year = newDate.getFullYear();
  let month = newDate.getMonth() + 1;
  month = month < 10 ? '0' + month : month;
  return month + '/' + '01/' + year;
}

document.getElementById('myFrame').src = 'http://zumdb-prod.itg.ti.com/zum/AppServlet?action=aotoolFe&jspURL=clusterTools/toolsetFe.jsp&fegoaltype=RAW&eedbListName=ZUM_Wet_Met_Brooks_IOC_sorters&facility=DMOS5&monthDate='.concat(getDate());
```

Comment: This works perfectly. I have two sections that will use this but the src will be slightly different.

Comment: I tried copying this code and placing it twice...I  changed the "myFrame" to reflect the ID in the div but it gives me an error saying Uncaught SyntaxError: Identifier 'getDate' has already been declared Only one of them gets populated.

Comment: Here is where I call myFrame `<div> <iframe id="myFrame" frameborder="0" scrolling="yes" src="" style="width:100%; height:550px; -ms-zoom: .995; -webkit-transform: scale(.995); -webkit-transform-origin: 0 0; -o-transform: scale(0.995); -o-transform-origin: 0 0;"></iframe>   </div>`

Comment: I call another myFrame1 `<div>
<iframe id="myFrame1" frameborder="0" scrolling="yes" src="" style="width:100%; height:550px; -ms-zoom: .995; -webkit-transform: scale(.995); -webkit-transform-origin: 0 0; -o-transform: scale(0.995); -o-transform-origin: 0 0;"></iframe>
 </div>`

Comment: @Dc5nipe you tried pasting the function declaration twice? You only need to have that code once and then you can repeatedly call it if you're within the same scope. Not sure if that's what you meant. If you want, you can paste the JavaScript example of what you mean.

Comment: I put an update of the code I have in the original question. I didn't know how to add the full code in the comments section. since it limits your characters. Sorry still new to stack overflow.

Comment: @Dc5nipe in this case, there's no need to include two script tags and two separate declarations of the function. The function only needs to be declared once. If for some reason you need to use two separate script tags here, because you've already declared the function once, it exists in the global namespace and thus is available to all scripts which are loaded after the script in which the function was declared.

Comment: @Dc5nipe the syntax error is because you're trying to declare a function which already exists.

Comment: Ok, I updated the script function and I still only get one populated.

Comment: @Dc5nipe I just tried this in jsfiddle using the information you provided [link to fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0d6h3sj4/). While the iframe itself didn't load, if I look at the source in the element using developer tools it appears that it populated the url correctly in both cases.

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
    <div>
    <iframe id="frame" frameborder="0" scrolling="yes" src=""></iframe>
    </div>
<script>
    var b = new Date();
        var y = b.getFullYear();
        var m = b.getMonth();
        var d = b.getDate();
        var newDate = d < 10 ? '0' + d : d;
        var newMonth = m < 9 ? '0' + (m + 1) : m + 1;

        document.getElementById("frame").src ="\nhttp://zumdb-prod.itg.ti.com/zum/AppServlet?action=aotoolFe&jspURL=clusterTools/toolsetFe.jsp&fegoaltype=RAW&eedbListName=ZUM_Wet_Met_Brooks_IOC_sorters&facility=DMOS5&monthDate=".concat(newDate, "/").concat(newMonth, "/").concat(y)

        console.log("\nhttp://zumdb-prod.itg.ti.com/zum/AppServlet?action=aotoolFe&jspURL=clusterTools/toolsetFe.jsp&fegoaltype=RAW&eedbListName=ZUM_Wet_Met_Brooks_IOC_sorters&facility=DMOS5&monthDate=".concat(newDate, "/").concat(newMonth, "/").concat(y))
</script>
```